# Make model reference abstract model in one-to-many

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, abstract-class

I'm pretty new to Django and right now I'm trying to understand the use of abstract models. Let's say you're writing a blogging service and you want both authenticated and anonymous users to be able to comment blog posts.

While scenario is pretty trivial for authenticated users (just having a foreign key to reference a specific user), it's not that straightforward when `Authors` are not just `User`s but either `AnonymousAuthor`s or `RegisteredAuthor`s.

The direct approach here is building a hierarchy of classes:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class AnonymousAuthor(Author):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  def display_name(self):
    return self.name

class RegisteredAuthor(Author):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  def display_name(self):
    return self.user.user_name
```

And then `BlogPostComment` can be defined like this:

```
class BlogPostComment(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
  ...
```

I like this approach because no matter who the author is, I can easily build the list of comments just by iterating over `BlogPostComment`s set and calling `display_name()` for each of them. The only problem here is that it doesn't work. Django says:

```
AssertionError: ForeignKey cannot define a relation with abstract class Author
```

What is solution here?

**Update**

I know that [Generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) can help here. But is it the only solution? Feels like overkill.

Comment: Generic relations is probably the best solution (think about how your foreign key relationship would be implemented in the database).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generic relations are the solution for creating a foreign key to many, unlike models. In general with inheritance if you have:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    ...

class Dog(Animal):
    ...
```

And then later:

```
models.ForeignKey(Animal)
```

You can store a `Dog` as the foreign key just as well, because a `Dog` is-a `Animal`. However, in the case of abstract classes, these are not eligible to be set as the destination of a foreign key because they don't *exist*. Django's "abstract" model is closer to the definition of a "mixin": they are never instantiated on their own, but rather used to compose some other class that is instantiated.

So you've got three choices here:

1. Change `Author` to a standard model instead of abstract. Then you can create foreign keys to `Author` and pass in any subclass of `Author` your like.
2. Use generic foreign keys
3. Don't break up the models in the first place.

The last choice here is actually your best bet because there's no reason to have separate author tables when the only defining difference is whether they are registered or anonymous. That is a *state* of an object, not a different type of object. Just like it would be inappropriate to have something like a `BlueCar` class. You have a `Car` class and "blue" is the value of it's `color` attribute instead.

If you insist on separate models. You can then use proxy models. Where `AnonymousAuthor` and `RegisterAuthor` are simply aliases for `Author` (they don't get their own tables), but having an alias allows you to change or add customized methods, and in particular the ability to specify a custom manager that automatically filters `Author` to just return "anonymous" or "registered" types, respectively.

Comment: So, what you mean is that best solution here is just to have a single `Author` class with 2 properties: `name` (`CharField`) and `user` (reference to specific user) and when I need to render the author, I just need to display `user.username` if `user` is set and `name` otherwise?

Comment: Exactly. And then if you wanted to create proxy models, you could use custom managers that filter on `user__isnull`, i.e. `filter(user__isnull=True)` would return "anonymous" authors, while `filter(user__isnull=False)` would return "registered" authors. Obviously, that also means that `user` would need to have `null=True`.